# Can I change previously unlocked game levels into locked locked by updating game?

Tags: unity, android

I have 14 unlocked levels in my android game so that the player can play whichever he want. Can I make those 14 levels locked in next update?
Players who previously reached 8th level would have to play from level 1 after the updating game.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? If I was a player of your game and you did that to me I would consider it to be a dick move. Updates should not remove player progress.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a summary of how you're currently saving which levels the player has unlocked.

Answer (score 1):

When you make an update on the Play Store, you have to upload a new `.apk`. This new file can be anything you want, even an entirely different game, so if you know how to make two versions of the game, one with unlocked levels and one with locked, this shouldn't be a problem.

> Player who reached 8th level will have to play from level 1 after the
>   updating game

If by "unlock" you mean that you want to erase the save file of the player, so they start all over again, this could be tricky. I don't know of any way to remove save files on update, but when saving data you can add a version prefix to the key, something like "v1.0-level", so when you update, the app will search for "v1.5-level" and fail, forcing the player to start over.

Comment: If the save file itself includes a version # internally, couldn't the app could simply ignore older versions when loading & overwrite them when saving?

Comment: @Pikalek  kinda assumed OP is using `PlayerPrefs` since `unity` is tagged, which is the most handy way to handle saves, as you don't have to bother with files and read/write permissions.